# Better way to write this if statement?

Tags: python, comparison

I have this tkinter GUI, and I need to get the values from the entries and compare.
`self.hystInt.get()` is the way to access the string in the string variable in the Entry. *I have to write this for every variable so it ends up looking really ugly.

```
if (self.hystInt.get().isdigit() and int(self.hystInt.get()) >= 200 and int(self.hystInt.get()) <= 500):
```

Comment: how many entries do you have? Table driven design might be more appropriate than repeating *ugly* code blocks.

Comment: while the genesis of this code may have been a tkinter program, the question really has nothing to do with tkinter. I recommend removing the tkinter tag. The question and answer is equally valid for any objects that require a `get()` to retrieve the value.

Comment: A possibility here is to use Python more advanced descriptors to get the variables authomatically "get" and "set" with an " = "  statement - like the "property"  built in function allows you to do - but I'd specialize the getters and setters in this case to account for the validation as well. Feel free do direct message me if you want to go this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you can use Python's unusual comparison syntax like this:

```
if (self.hystInt.get().isdigit() and (200 <= int(self.hystInt.get()) <= 500)):
```

Comment: I think the original code is more readable. This code requires one to stop and mentally parse the code.

Comment: @Bryan: just when you don't know Python and are too used with other programing Languages. The logic way e learn back in school, with Math uses the same syntax as Python allows: `x < y < z` -- and it is clearly more readble than `(x < y)  and (y < z)` which was the only parseable way back when C was invented.

Comment: @jsbueno: I agree that in some circumstances it is easier to read, especially when it is of the form `x < y < z`. However, in this case there are too many syntactic character plus and `and` clause that make it hard to scan the line IMO.

Answer (score 10):

```
def validate(num):
    try:
        return 200 <= int(num) <= 500
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Simple is good!

Comment: +1 for the Python way, Better to ask forgiveness than permission.

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
try:
    hystInt= int(self.hystInt.get())
    if 200 <= hystInt <= 500:
        Valid.
    else:
        Out of bounds.
except ValueError, e:
    Not even a number.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a temporary variable? I think the real problem (both in in readability and (very!) marginally in performance) is that you're calling the `get()` method three times.

```
histint = self.hystInt.get()
if (histint.isdigit() and 
    (200 <= int(histint) <= 500))
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the tedious coding you could do something along these lines:

```
valid_hystInt = lambda self, low, high: (
    self.hystInt.get().isdigit() and (low <= int(self.hystInt.get()) <= high)
)

class Class:
    hystInt = HystInt() # or whatever

    def some_method(self):
        if valid_hystInt(self, 200, 500):
            pass # use it
```

or possibly the even more general:

```
valid_int_field = lambda field, low, high: (
    field.get().isdigit() and (low <= int(field.get()) <= high)
)

class Class:
    hystInt = HystInt() # or whatever

    def some_method(self):
        if valid_int_field(self.hystInt, 200, 500):
            pass # use it
```